# Sharing content between sites with MSM and Structure

Tags: add-on, structure, multi-site-manager

I have a MSM installation that will be powering 3 different sites.  One site is essentially a small stand-alone brochure site and is running fine.  The other two are Site A - default site w/ most of the content and Site B, a smaller site that is going to re-use some content from A.

The short question is: Is it possible to use Structure and MSM to share content between sites?

Longer details:

All the sites are using Structure to manage pages.  In Site B, I have duplicated the channels and Structure layout for this particular page I'm trying to display.  I have also duplicated the template wich includes the channel:entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="businesses"
    limit="1"
    site="default_site"
}
```

The only difference between Site A template and Site B is the `site="default_site"` tag.  Everything else in the templates, channels, and entries are the same between sites.

Side note - my navigation templates use a similar channel entries tag (limited to a specific category id) and they display fine.  The correct content entries are being displayed in the nav on Site B.

Answer (score 4):

You can share content, but all navigation and page data is site-specific, so you can't call from one into another unfortunately. It's just an EE/MSM limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we have come up with is to use the Playa add-on and link the content that way.  This requires us to create the pages on Site B via Structure, but solves the navigation and page-date restriction Travis mentions.  This also allows us to add in Site B specific content as needed (another client requirement).